# Django forms - ChoiceField with range of numbers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

```
class House(models.Model):
    floors = IntegerField()  # 10 floors for example

class Flat(models.Model):
    floor = IntegerField(null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])  # then here should be from 1 to 10 or None
    house = ForeignKey(House)

class FlatForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Flat
        fields = ['floor']
        widgets = {'floor': .....}  # I don't know what to do here. Select widget?
```

Hello. Any tips how I can implement a form where I can choose a floor for a flat within the number of floors in the house?

---

I made dynamic choices upload via Select2 and API.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices),
something along the lines of the following should do:

```py
class House(models.Model):
    Floor = models.IntegerChoices('Floor', range(1,11))
    floors = IntegerField(choices=Floor.choices)
```

(I can't test this right now – maybe you need `list(range(1,11))`.)

I don't think you need to change anything about the widgets in the form unless you're unhappy with the default widget.